# Postgresql successfully deploying with docker-compose but not in docker stack deploy

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, kong

This is my docker-compose.yml file which has the **postgresql** to be deployed first than the service **migrations** and other services will be deployed.

> With docker-compose up its is successfully deploying and ready but
> when trying to deploy same with docker stack deploy it is stuck in
> some part and restarting. I have provide the logs down bellow. From
> that part it gets restarted again not moving ahead to ready state.

***docker service logs of postgresql service***

```
stackapi_kong-database.1.ldulsrc2q7yc@ip131.ip-X-3-111.eu    | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
    stackapi_kong-database.1.yk6kjyhcfawr@ip131.ip-X-3-111.eu    | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
    stackapi_kong-database.1.zjyhav9h27s6@ip131.ip-X-3-111.eu    | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
    stackapi_kong-database.1.poy4nxov7ua1@ip131.ip-X-3-111.eu    | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
    stackapi_kong-database.1.poy4nxov7ua1@ip131.ip-X-3-111.eu    | This user must also own the server process.
    stackapi_kong-database.1.ldulsrc2q7yc@ip131.ip-X-3-111.eu    | This user must also own the server process.
    stackapi_kong-database.1.yk6kjyhcfawr@ip131.ip-X-3-111.eu    | This user must also own the server process.
    stackapi_kong-database.1.zjyhav9h27s6@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | This user must also own the server process.
    stackapi_kong-database.1.zjyhav9h27s6@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | 
    stackapi_kong-database.1.poy4nxov7ua1@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | 
    stackapi_kong-database.1.ldulsrc2q7yc@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | 
    stackapi_kong-database.1.yk6kjyhcfawr@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | 
    stackapi_kong-database.1.yk6kjyhcfawr@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
    stackapi_kong-database.1.zjyhav9h27s6@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
    stackapi_kong-database.1.poy4nxov7ua1@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
    stackapi_kong-database.1.ldulsrc2q7yc@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
    stackapi_kong-database.1.ldulsrc2q7yc@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
    stackapi_kong-database.1.yk6kjyhcfawr@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
    stackapi_kong-database.1.zjyhav9h27s6@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
    stackapi_kong-database.1.poy4nxov7ua1@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
    stackapi_kong-database.1.poy4nxov7ua1@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
    stackapi_kong-database.1.ldulsrc2q7yc@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
    stackapi_kong-database.1.yk6kjyhcfawr@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
    stackapi_kong-database.1.zjyhav9h27s6@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
    stackapi_kong-database.1.zjyhav9h27s6@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | 
    stackapi_kong-database.1.poy4nxov7ua1@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | 
    stackapi_kong-database.1.ldulsrc2q7yc@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | 
    stackapi_kong-database.1.yk6kjyhcfawr@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | 
    stackapi_kong-database.1.yk6kjyhcfawr@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | Data page checksums are disabled.
    stackapi_kong-database.1.zjyhav9h27s6@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | Data page checksums are disabled.
    stackapi_kong-database.1.poy4nxov7ua1@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | Data page checksums are disabled.
    stackapi_kong-database.1.ldulsrc2q7yc@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | Data page checksums are disabled.
    stackapi_kong-database.1.ldulsrc2q7yc@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | 
    stackapi_kong-database.1.yk6kjyhcfawr@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | 
    stackapi_kong-database.1.zjyhav9h27s6@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | 
    stackapi_kong-database.1.poy4nxov7ua1@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | 
    stackapi_kong-database.1.poy4nxov7ua1@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.ldulsrc2q7yc@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.yk6kjyhcfawr@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.zjyhav9h27s6@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.zjyhav9h27s6@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | creating subdirectories ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.poy4nxov7ua1@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | creating subdirectories ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.ldulsrc2q7yc@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | creating subdirectories ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.yk6kjyhcfawr@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | creating subdirectories ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.yk6kjyhcfawr@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | selecting default max_connections ... 100
    stackapi_kong-database.1.zjyhav9h27s6@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | selecting default max_connections ... 100
    stackapi_kong-database.1.poy4nxov7ua1@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | selecting default max_connections ... 100
    stackapi_kong-database.1.ldulsrc2q7yc@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | selecting default max_connections ... 100
    stackapi_kong-database.1.ldulsrc2q7yc@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
    stackapi_kong-database.1.yk6kjyhcfawr@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
    stackapi_kong-database.1.zjyhav9h27s6@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
    stackapi_kong-database.1.poy4nxov7ua1@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
    stackapi_kong-database.1.poy4nxov7ua1@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
    stackapi_kong-database.1.ldulsrc2q7yc@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
    stackapi_kong-database.1.yk6kjyhcfawr@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
    stackapi_kong-database.1.zjyhav9h27s6@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
    stackapi_kong-database.1.zjyhav9h27s6@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | creating configuration files ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.poy4nxov7ua1@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | creating configuration files ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.ldulsrc2q7yc@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | creating configuration files ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.yk6kjyhcfawr@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | creating configuration files ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.yk6kjyhcfawr@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | creating template1 database in /var/lib/postgresql/data/base/1 ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.zjyhav9h27s6@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | creating template1 database in /var/lib/postgresql/data/base/1 ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.poy4nxov7ua1@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | creating template1 database in /var/lib/postgresql/data/base/1 ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.ldulsrc2q7yc@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | creating template1 database in /var/lib/postgresql/data/base/1 ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.ldulsrc2q7yc@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | initializing pg_authid ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.yk6kjyhcfawr@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | initializing pg_authid ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.zjyhav9h27s6@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | initializing pg_authid ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.poy4nxov7ua1@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | initializing pg_authid ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.poy4nxov7ua1@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | initializing dependencies ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.ldulsrc2q7yc@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | initializing dependencies ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.yk6kjyhcfawr@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | initializing dependencies ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.zjyhav9h27s6@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | initializing dependencies ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.zjyhav9h27s6@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | creating system views ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.poy4nxov7ua1@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | creating system views ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.ldulsrc2q7yc@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | creating system views ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.yk6kjyhcfawr@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | creating system views ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.yk6kjyhcfawr@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | loading system objects' descriptions ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.zjyhav9h27s6@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | loading system objects' descriptions ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.poy4nxov7ua1@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | loading system objects' descriptions ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.ldulsrc2q7yc@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | loading system objects' descriptions ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.ldulsrc2q7yc@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | creating collations ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.yk6kjyhcfawr@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | creating collations ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.zjyhav9h27s6@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | creating collations ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.poy4nxov7ua1@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | creating collations ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.poy4nxov7ua1@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | creating conversions ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.ldulsrc2q7yc@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | creating conversions ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.yk6kjyhcfawr@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | creating conversions ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.zjyhav9h27s6@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | creating conversions ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.zjyhav9h27s6@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | creating dictionaries ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.poy4nxov7ua1@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | creating dictionaries ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.ldulsrc2q7yc@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | creating dictionaries ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.yk6kjyhcfawr@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | creating dictionaries ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.yk6kjyhcfawr@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | setting privileges on built-in objects ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.zjyhav9h27s6@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | setting privileges on built-in objects ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.poy4nxov7ua1@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | setting privileges on built-in objects ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.ldulsrc2q7yc@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | setting privileges on built-in objects ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.ldulsrc2q7yc@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | creating information schema ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.yk6kjyhcfawr@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | creating information schema ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.zjyhav9h27s6@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | creating information schema ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.poy4nxov7ua1@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | creating information schema ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.poy4nxov7ua1@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | loading PL/pgSQL server-side language ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.ldulsrc2q7yc@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | loading PL/pgSQL server-side language ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.yk6kjyhcfawr@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | loading PL/pgSQL server-side language ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.zjyhav9h27s6@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | loading PL/pgSQL server-side language ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.zjyhav9h27s6@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | vacuuming database template1 ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.poy4nxov7ua1@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | vacuuming database template1 ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.ldulsrc2q7yc@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | vacuuming database template1 ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.yk6kjyhcfawr@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | vacuuming database template1 ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.yk6kjyhcfawr@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | copying template1 to template0 ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.zjyhav9h27s6@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | copying template1 to template0 ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.poy4nxov7ua1@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | copying template1 to template0 ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.ldulsrc2q7yc@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | copying template1 to template0 ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.ldulsrc2q7yc@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | copying template1 to postgres ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.yk6kjyhcfawr@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | copying template1 to postgres ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.zjyhav9h27s6@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | copying template1 to postgres ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.poy4nxov7ua1@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | copying template1 to postgres ... ok
    stackapi_kong-database.1.poy4nxov7ua1@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | syncing data to disk ... stackapi_kong-database.1.ldulsrc2q7yc@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | syncing data to disk ... stackapi_kong-database.1.yk6kjyhcfawr@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | syncing data to disk ... stackapi_kong-database.1.zjyhav9h27s6@ip131.ip-X-36-111.eu    | syncing data to disk ...
```

> Here is the docker-compose file that I have used to make it docker
> stack compatible. I  have added the service to same network and making
> them to run under same manager node for now. Previously it was in
> version 3 . I changed it to version 3.4 too

***docker-compose.yml file***

```
kong-database:
    image: "postgres:9.5"
    restart: always
    networks:
        - api-net
    environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: kong
        POSTGRES_DB: kong
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "postgres"]
        interval: 5s
        timeout: 5s
        retries: 5

    deploy:
        mode: replicated
        replicas: 1
        placement:
            constraints:
                - node.role == manager

kong-migration:
    image: "kong:latest"
    networks:
        - api-net
    command: "kong migrations up"
    environment:
        KONG_PG_HOST: kong-database
    depends_on:
        - kong-database
    deploy:
        mode: replicated
        replicas: 1
        placement:
            constraints:
                  - node.role == manager

kong:
#build: ./dockerfiles/kong
    image: "ncarlier:latest"
    networks:
        - api-net
    environment:
        KONG_PG_HOST: kong-database
        KONG_PROXY_LISTEN: 0.0.0.0:8000
        KONG_PROXY_LISTEN_SSL: 0.0.0.0:8443
        KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN: 0.0.0.0:8001
        KONG_CUSTOM_PLUGINS: oidc
    depends_on:
        - kong-database
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://kong:8001"]
        interval: 5s
        timeout: 2s
        retries: 15
    ports:
        - "8001:8001"
        - "8000:8000"
    deploy:
        mode: replicated
        replicas: 1
        placement:
            constraints:
                - node.role == manager
konga:
    image: "pantsel/konga:latest"
    restart: always
    networks:
        - api-net
    environment:
        NODE_ENV: production
    depends_on:
        - kong
    ports:
        - "1337:1337"
```